How to create a dictionary with a key and a list of values from multiple folders and files
I have a three folders in GCS and I want to create a dictionary that has the folder name as the key and its contents as the values with without the file_type as the values. How do I do this?
For a bit more clarity, the folders are databases and I run
select * from information_schema

From there, I break down the files as needed and then place the csv files in the folders.
After the folder and contents are created I send the dictionary to other teams.
Example:
In the following folder I have these files
temp_folder/stats/data_transfer/
extraction.csv
united_sync.csv
united_configs.csv
united_history.csv

In another folder
temp_folder/stats/appointments/
I have the following
appointment_history.csv
appointment_configs.csv
appointment_transactions.csv

Expected Outcome:
folders_dict = {
    'data_transfer': ['extraction', 'united_sync', 'united_configs', 'united_history'],
    'appointment': ['appointment_history', 'appointment_configs', 'appointment_transactions']
}


Just read the directory's contents and then assemble a data structure from that. Where exactly is your problem with those two parts? What have you tried already that didn't give you the expected results? As it stands, you just described a task, but not a problem. Since this also looks like homework, you should also demonstrate some effort from your side. For reference, read [ask] and [tour].

What about folders within folders? Did your tutor discuss that possibility with you?

"the folders are databases" What?

How about something like this which reads files and put it in an list inside a dict:
import os

folders = {
    'appointment': 'temp_folder/stats/appointments/',
    'data_transfer': 'temp_folder/stats/data_transfer'
}

folder_contents = {}

for folder_name, folder_path in folders.items():
    folder_contents[folder_name] = []
    files = os.listdir(folder_path)
    for file in files:
        name, extension = os.path.splitext(file)
        folder_contents[folder_name].append(name)

print(folder_contents)


What array are you referring to? Why is folders a dictionary rather than just a list of directory names from which the dictionary key can be derived? Mapping 'appointment' to 'temp_folder/stats/appointments/' seems rather an odd decision

it's was by design so you can have as many folders as you want and the path could be anywhere you want. The folders dict is a list of keys and paths to scan, then it creates another dictionary, folder_contents with the same key, and files in for that key. You could easily derive it by using an array ['folder1'] and using os.path.basename(path)

@YounElan You don't have an array. You hava a list.

@Matthias : correct, it's actually a list inside a dict. I was using the word array in a generic term


import os

def get_folder_contents_with_suffix(folder_paths, suffix):
    
    folders_dict = {}

    # Iterate through the folder paths
    for folder_name, folder_path in folder_paths.items():
        try:
            # List all files in the folder
            files = os.listdir(folder_path)
            # Filter and extract file names without extensions if they have the specified suffix
            file_names = [os.path.splitext(file)[0] for file in files if file.endswith(suffix) and os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, file))]
            # Add the folder name and its file names to the dictionary
            folders_dict[folder_name] = file_names
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print(f"Error: The folder '{folder_path}' does not exist.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred while processing the folder '{folder_path}': {e}")

    return folders_dict

# Define your folder paths
folder_paths = {
    'appointment': 'temp_folder/stats/appointments/',
    'data_transfer': 'temp_folder/stats/data_transfer/'
}

# Define the suffix to filter files
suffix = '.csv'

# Get the folder contents with the specified suffix
folder_contents = get_folder_contents_with_suffix(folder_paths, suffix)

# Print the resulting dictionary
print(folder_contents)



Making some assumptions here.

You don't want a recursive search
You're only interested in CSV files
You have a Python list of folder (directory) names that are accessible from your current working directory

On that basis it's as simple as:
from pathlib import Path

list_of_folders = [
    Path("temp_folder/stats/data_transfer"),
    Path("temp_folder/stats/appointments"),
]

result = {}

for folder in list_of_folders:
    key = folder.name
    for file in folder.glob("*.csv"):
        result.setdefault(key, []).append(file.stem)

print(result)

Given the folder hierarchy in the OP and their contents, this would produce:
{'data_transfer': ['united_configs', 'united_history', 'extraction', 'united_sync'], 'appointments': ['appointment_configs', 'united_history', 'appointment_history']}


from pathlib import Path

folders_dict = {}
for folder in Path(".").glob("*/"):
    csv_files = list(Path(f"./{folder}").glob("**/*.csv"))

    if csv_files:
        folders_dict[str(folder)] = [
            str(file.relative_to(folder).with_suffix("")) for file in csv_files
        ]


Please describe the logic behind "your" code. Why do you start in the CWD rather than from a list of folders as suggested in the OP? Does the OP say anything about recursive searching?
